# What is the difference between String sorting and string comparison. Are not they the same thing as we have to compare the string in order to sort it?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, comparison, big-o

Suppose we had an algorithm that took in an array of strings, sorted each string, and then sorted the full array. What would the runtime be?

I am a little bit confused about the solution 
On the 3rd line its written `Sorting each string is O(s lo g s),` 
On the 5th line its written `Each string comparison takes 0(s ) time.`
As I understand even to sort a string we have to first compare it so are not they the same thing. Why are the runtime different?

```
• Let S be the length of the longest string.
• Let a be the length of the array.
Now we can work through this in parts:
• Sorting each string isO(s lo g s),
• We have to do this for every string (and there are a strings), so that's 0( a* s lo g s).
• Now we have to sort all the strings. There a re a strings, so you'll may be inclined to say that this takes 0( a
l o g a) time. This is what most candidates would say. You should also take into account that you need
to compare the strings. Each string comparison takes 0(s ) time.There are 0( a lo g a) comparisons,
therefore this will takeO(a* s lo g a)time .
If you add up these two parts, you get 0(a*s ( lo g a + lo g s)) .
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things being sorted here: First each string is sorted. I take it this means that the characters of the string are placed in order. For this, we do not need to compare strings, we need to compare *characters*. Comparing two characters is *O(1)*, so sorting a single string is *O(s log s)* (where *s* is the length of the string), which we have to repeat *a* times.

After that, we sort the array of sorted strings. For this, we need to compare strings. Two strings could differ only in the last character, so we have to scan through the strings to compare them. This means that comparing two strings is *O(s)* (where *s* is the length of the strings). We have *O(a log a)* comparisons, so multiplying those two gives a complexity of *O(s * a log a)* for sorting the string array.

Combining these complexities gives the complexity in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The run time is different because for sorting you revisit the elements of the array multiple times to compare it with other elements and figure out it's right place. 
See the below animation of quick short which I shamelessly picked from wikipedia, the first element is being revisited thrice.

[image]

But in comparison you compare 0th element then 1st element... nth element to figure out the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Taking it step by step

Comparision
Let us compare two strings. To complete a comparison(in worst case), every letter of one string needs to be compared with every letter of the other. So the complexity here is O(s) where S is the length of the strings(considering they are of equal length)

Sorting
Now, take a single string and try to sort it, To sort a string, every letter of the string of length N needs to be compared with the remaining (N-1) letters of the same string. So, for one letter, you do N-1 comparisons. So if you continue to do this, you will do (N-1) + (N-2)(since we already sorted 1 character before this)  + (N-3) +... 1 comparisons totally. Note that this is the sum of N natural numbers approximately equal to n(n+1)/2 => therefore the complexity is O(N^2)

Algorithms like quick sort, merge sort etc. tend to optimize on this solution to bring it down to O(N log n)

Coming back to your question,

On the 5th line its written Each string comparison takes 0(s ) time. 
This is because, in sorting a single string, your comparison for a single letter takes only O(1) (comparing one alphabet with another) 
Here, you are sorting an array of strings EACH of length S( so you need to do comparison of 2 strings of length S) and it is not O(1)